# Not able to generate XSD (JaxB) to Java in case of build in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb

I have below mention gradle configuration. When I use any build command it prints.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

My gradle configuration is.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.dvsts.nextgen.restcisco'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.dvsts.nextgen.restcisco.Application"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}


task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.dvsts.nextgen.restcisco.Application'
    }
    baseName = 'ciso-cdr-rest'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.4'

}



configurations {
    jaxb
}
dependencies {
    jaxb "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.7"
}

task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/xsds/cospace.xsd"
    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            // Create output directories
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            taskdef name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema, 'package': 'com.gdpotter.sample.iso_20022.seev_031_01_07') {
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: '**/*.java')
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: 'lines,vars,source',
                    includeantruntime: false,
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: '**/*.java')
                include(name: '*.java')
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: '**/*.java')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.7'
}

compileJava.dependsOn 'genJaxb'

jar {
    from genJaxb.classesDir
}
```

I have tried all possible combination. I want when build happens jaxb generated java classes should be added into classpath.

and in case of gradle build they should be included in jar file.

Comment: What do you see if you add the `--stacktrace` option to your Gradle command line, as recommended by the build output?

Comment: It worked. Actually by mistake I was using wrong package.